# Dynamic Row addition to the Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to add Array elements to the table.

Array elements are dynamic coming from the database. And i am creating the Row for adding the one row from the generated data and appending rowAfter to add the other array elements

Here is the code i have written -

```
var rowSpan = 0;
var rowSpan1 = 0;
for (element in data)
{
  // get products into an array
  var productsArray = data[element].products.split(',');
  var QuantityArray = data[element].quantity.split(',');
  var ChemistArray = data[element].Retailername.split(',');
  var PobArray = data[element].Pob.split(',');

  rowSpan = productsArray.length;
  rowSpan1 = ChemistArray.length;

  var row = '<tr>' +
 '<td rowspan="'+rowSpan+'">' + data[element].date + '</td>'+
 '<td rowspan="'+rowSpan+'">' + data[element].doctor_name + '</td>';

 // loop through products array
 var rowAfter = "";

 for (var i = 0; i < rowSpan; i++) {
   if(i == 0) {
     row += '<td>' + productsArray[i] + '</td>';
     row += '<td>' + QuantityArray[i] + '</td>';
     } else {
       rowAfter += '<tr><td>' + productsArray[i] + '</td><td>' + QuantityArray[i] + '</td>';
     }
 }

 for (var k = 0; k < rowSpan1; k++) {
   if(k == 0) {
     row += '<td>' + ChemistArray[k] + '</td>';
     row += '<td>' + PobArray[k] + '</td>';
   } else {
     rowAfter += '<td>' + ChemistArray[k] + '</td><td>' + PobArray[k] + '</td> </tr>';
   }
 }

 row +=

 '<td rowspan="'+rowSpan1+'">' + data[element].locations +'</td>'+
 '<td rowspan="'+rowSpan1+'">' + data[element].area + '</td>'+
 '</tr>';

 $('#tbody').append(row+rowAfter);
```

So as per the code I can finely display ProductArray and Quantity Array

And But i am not able to display the Chemist array after one another.

[image]

In the above Image i want to display data( Kapila and Kripa below the Chemist column) Some where making issue with tr and td.

Any help would really appreciated.

Data is a JSON Response -

[image]

In my case, ChemistArray(Retailername in response) contains 4 names and POBArray 4 values.

Comment: What is `data`? Please add all of your code to the question.

Comment: Seems like the chemist doesn't have other data except names, hence you need to add blank `td` before names to be consistent, Can update your code if we have the data pasted here

Comment: @Hiteshdua1 : Thanks for the response. data is a JSON Response . And i have edited the question with JSON Reponse image. Please take a look into it.

Comment: @JackBashford : Added the data in the Question. Please take a look into it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You need to share sample data in json format here, not image, so that this codes replicate the issue here, try adding manual 4 `<td></td>` before chemist name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an empty `<td></td>` as a "placeholder".

```
for (element in data) {
    var productsArray = data[element].products.split(',');
    var quantityArray = data[element].quantity.split(',');
    var chemistArray = data[element].Retailername.split(',');
    var pobArray = data[element].Pob.split(',');

    // find the largest row number
    var maxRows = Math.max(productsArray.length, quantityArray.length, chemistArray.length, pobArray.length);

    var content = '';
    var date = '<td rowspan="' + maxRows + '">' + data[element].date + '</td>';
    var doctorName = '<td rowspan="' + maxRows + '">' + data[element].doctor_name + '</td>';
    var locations = '<td rowspan="' + maxRows + '">' + data[element].locations + '</td>';
    var area = '<td rowspan="' + maxRows + '">' + data[element].area + '</td>';

    content += '<tr>' + date + doctorName;

    for (var row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
        // only add '<tr>' if row !== 0
        // It's because for the first row, we already have an open <tr> tag
        // from the line "content += '<tr>' + date + doctorName;"
        if (row !== 0) {
            content += '<tr>';
        }

        // the ternary operator is used to check whether there is items in the array
        // if yes, insert the value between the <td></td> tag
        // if not, just add an empty <td></td> to the content as a placeholder
        content += '<td>' + (productsArray[row] ? productsArray[row] : '') + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + (quantityArray[row] ? quantityArray[row] : '') + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + (chemistArray[row] ? chemistArray[row] : '') + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + (pobArray[row] ? pobArray[row] : '') + '</td>';

        // only add "locations + area + '</tr>'" if it is the first row
        // because locations and area will span the whole column
        if (row === 0) {
            content += locations + area + '</tr>';
        } else {
            content += '</tr>';
        }
    }

    $('#tbody').append(content);
}
```

`content += '<td>' + (productsArray[row] ? productsArray[row] : '') + '</td>';` is just a short-hand for

```
content += '<td>';

if (productsArray[row]) {
    content += productsArray[row];
} else {
    content += '';
}

content += '</td>';
```

If there is item in the `productsArray[row]`, let's say `productsArray[0]`, which is 'Sinarest', then `productsArray[row]` would be truthy. Else, if there is no more products in the array, such as `productsArray[3]` will gives us `undefined`, which is a falsy value and the corresponding conditional will be ran.

Comment: Excellent. One of the beautiful solution you gave me today. I really appreciate your work and the code changes you made. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I really need to analyze the logic which you have presented.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the logic in greater details. If there is still anything that you're unsure of, please let me know.